# Beginner, python - how to read a list from a file

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a Word document that is literally a list of lists, that is 8 pages long. Eg:

```
[['WTCS','Dec 21'],['THWD','Mar 22']...]
```

I am using Linux Mint, Python 3.2 and the IDLE interface, plus my own .py programs. I need to read and reference this list frequently and when I stored it inside .py programs it seemed to slow down the window considerably as I was editing code. How can I store this information in a separate file and read it into python? I have it in a .txt file now and tried the following code:

```
def readlist():
    f = open(r'/home/file.txt','r')
    info = list(f.read())
    return(info)
```

but I get each character as an element of a list. I also tried info = f.read() but I get a string. Thanks!

Comment: For saving Python objects to flat text files and loading them back again, look into [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). Alternatively, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the existing data into native Python objects.

Comment: I think you should look into using [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a Python list read from a text file from a text file as a string into a list using the [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "[['WTCS','Dec 21'],['THWD','Mar 22']]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[['WTCS', 'Dec 21'], ['THWD', 'Mar 22']]
```